# How to highlight words beginning with ‘@’ in Vim syntax?

Tags: regex, vim, syntax

I have a very simple Vim syntax file for personal notes. I would like to highlight people's name and I chose a Twitter-like syntax `@jonathan`.

I tried:

```
syntax match notesPerson "\<@\S\+"
```

To mean: words beginning with `@` and having at least one non-whitespace character. The problem is that `@` seems to be a special character in Vim regular expressions.

I tried to escape `\@` and enclose in brackets `[@]`, the usual tricks, but that didn't work. I could try something like `(^|\s)` (beginning of line or whitespace) but that's exactly the problem that word-boundary tries to solve.

Highlighting works on simplified regular expressions, so this is more a question of finding the right regex than anything else. What am I missing?

Comment: Why have you escaped your `+` in `\S\+`? Try `@\S+` or `\@\S+`, if `@` is considered special character in `vim`. I don't know about that.

Comment: @RohitJain Because vim syntax originates from BRE. It must be escaped to be special.

Comment: @ZyX.. Oh! I didn't knew that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`@` is a special character only if you have enabled the “very magic”
mode by having `\v` somewhere in the pattern prior to that `@`.

You have another problem here: `@` does not start a new word. `\<` is
not just “word boundary” like perl/PCRE’s `\b`, but “*left* word
boundary” (in help: “beginning of the word”) meaning that `\<` must be
followed by some keyword character. As `@` is not normally a keyword
character, pattern `\<@` will never match. (And even if it was like
`\b`, it would match constructs like `abc@def` which is definitely not
what you want for the aforementioned reasons.)

You should use `\k\@<!@\k\S*` instead: `\k\@<!` ensures that `@` is not preceded by any keyword character, `\k\S*` makes sure that first character of the name is a keyword one (you could probably also use `@\<\S\+`).

There is another solution: include `@` into `'iskeyword'` option and leave the regex as is:

```
:setlocal iskeyword+=@-@
```

See `:help 'isfname'` for the explanation why `@-@` is used here.
(The `'iskeyword'` option has exactly the same syntax and will,
in fact, redirect you there for the explanation.)